# How do record video stream data as mp4 in webRTC android?

Tags: android, stream, video-streaming, webrtc

Please help me! I used this example in https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC to streaming video and audio from a android device to an other android device.In this example, they used 2 librarys is : libjingle_peerConnection and SocketIo client but i don't know how to save streaming data as h.264 format?

Comment: @ADM is there any code for record remote or local stream of Webrtc? i didn't see any code in android for this issue! i see only for nod js code with MediaStreamRecord for recorde remote stream

Comment: Try to run the project . See flag `saveRemoteVideoToFile` in `CallActivity` . I think `VideoFileRenderer` is responsible fro recording.

Comment: you guys find solution ..?

Comment: hi @ADM i use it and record video in android. its work with VideoFrame but tht didn't any sound? have any idea? thanks

Comment: Sorry no . If its working in sample then there must be some issue with your code . try to test the AppRTC sample first for recording

Comment: @ADM i cant run this project because it have server problem. and cant be run and  test it. i use only sample code in my project.

Comment: please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031340/android-webrtc-record-video-from-the-stream-coming-from-the-other-peer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of tries and hard work about this project, I found the solution for saving video as mp4 without any problem.

add this VideoFileRenderer.java to your project

```
package org.webrtc;

import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

import org.webrtc.audio.AudioDeviceModule;
import org.webrtc.audio.JavaAudioDeviceModule;
import org.webrtc.audio.JavaAudioDeviceModule.SamplesReadyCallback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class VideoFileRenderer implements VideoSink, SamplesReadyCallback {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoFileRenderer";
    private final HandlerThread renderThread;
    private final Handler renderThreadHandler;
    private final HandlerThread audioThread;
    private final Handler audioThreadHandler;
    private int outputFileWidth = -1;
    private int outputFileHeight = -1;
    private ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers;
    private ByteBuffer[] audioInputBuffers;
    private ByteBuffer[] audioOutputBuffers;
    private EglBase eglBase;
    private EglBase.Context sharedContext;
    private VideoFrameDrawer frameDrawer;

    // TODO: these ought to be configurable as well
    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";    // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static final int FRAME_RATE = 30;               // 30fps
    private static final int IFRAME_INTERVAL = 5;           // 5 seconds between I-frames

    private MediaMuxer mediaMuxer;
    private MediaCodec encoder;
    private MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo, audioBufferInfo;
    private int trackIndex = -1;
    private int audioTrackIndex;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private GlRectDrawer drawer;
    private Surface surface;
    private MediaCodec audioEncoder;
    private AudioDeviceModule audioDeviceModule;

    public VideoFileRenderer(String outputFile, final EglBase.Context sharedContext, boolean withAudio) throws IOException {
        renderThread = new HandlerThread(TAG + "RenderThread");
        renderThread.start();
        renderThreadHandler = new Handler(renderThread.getLooper());
        if (withAudio) {
            audioThread = new HandlerThread(TAG + "AudioThread");
            audioThread.start();
            audioThreadHandler = new Handler(audioThread.getLooper());
        } else {
            audioThread = null;
            audioThreadHandler = null;
        }
        bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        this.sharedContext = sharedContext;

        // Create a MediaMuxer.  We can't add the video track and start() the muxer here,
        // because our MediaFormat doesn't have the Magic Goodies.  These can only be
        // obtained from the encoder after it has started processing data.
        mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile,
                MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        audioTrackIndex = withAudio ? -1 : 0;
    }

    private void initVideoEncoder() {
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, outputFileWidth, outputFileHeight);

        // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
        // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
                MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 6000000);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);

        // Create a MediaCodec encoder and configure it with our format.  Get a Surface
        // we can use for input and wrap it with a class that handles the EGL work.
        try {
            encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
            encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            renderThreadHandler.post(() -> {
                eglBase = EglBase.create(sharedContext, EglBase.CONFIG_RECORDABLE);
                surface = encoder.createInputSurface();
                eglBase.createSurface(surface);
                eglBase.makeCurrent();
                drawer = new GlRectDrawer();
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrame(VideoFrame frame) {
        frame.retain();
        if (outputFileWidth == -1) {
            outputFileWidth = frame.getRotatedWidth();
            outputFileHeight = frame.getRotatedHeight();
            initVideoEncoder();
        }
        renderThreadHandler.post(() -> renderFrameOnRenderThread(frame));
    }

    private void renderFrameOnRenderThread(VideoFrame frame) {
        if (frameDrawer == null) {
            frameDrawer = new VideoFrameDrawer();
        }
        frameDrawer.drawFrame(frame, drawer, null, 0, 0, outputFileWidth, outputFileHeight);
        frame.release();
        drainEncoder();
        eglBase.swapBuffers();
    }

    /**
     * Release all resources. All already posted frames will be rendered first.
     */
    public void release() {
        isRunning = false;
        if (audioThreadHandler != null)
            audioThreadHandler.post(() -> {
                if (audioEncoder != null) {
                    audioEncoder.stop();
                    audioEncoder.release();
                }
                audioThread.quit();
            });
        renderThreadHandler.post(() -> {
            if (encoder != null) {
                encoder.stop();
                encoder.release();
            }
            eglBase.release();
            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            renderThread.quit();
        });
    }

    private boolean encoderStarted = false;
    private volatile boolean muxerStarted = false;
    private long videoFrameStart = 0;

    private void drainEncoder() {
        if (!encoderStarted) {
            encoder.start();
            encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
            encoderStarted = true;
            return;
        }
        while (true) {
            int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000);
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                break;
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                Log.e(TAG, "encoder output buffers changed");
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();

                Log.e(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);
                trackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                if (audioTrackIndex != -1 && !muxerStarted) {
                    mediaMuxer.start();
                    muxerStarted = true;
                }
                if (!muxerStarted)
                    break;
            } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result fr om encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
            } else { // encoderStatus >= 0
                try {
                    ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                    if (encodedData == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                        break;
                    }
                    // It's usually necessary to adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo.
                    encodedData.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);
                    if (videoFrameStart == 0 && bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs != 0) {
                        videoFrameStart = bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;
                    }
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs -= videoFrameStart;
                    if (muxerStarted)
                        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedData, bufferInfo);
                    isRunning = isRunning && (bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) == 0;
                    encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                    if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private long presTime = 0L;

    private void drainAudio() {
        if (audioBufferInfo == null)
            audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        while (true) {
            int encoderStatus = audioEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(audioBufferInfo, 10000);
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                break;
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                audioOutputBuffers = audioEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
                Log.w(TAG, "encoder output buffers changed");
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                MediaFormat newFormat = audioEncoder.getOutputFormat();

                Log.w(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);
                audioTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                if (trackIndex != -1 && !muxerStarted) {
                    mediaMuxer.start();
                    muxerStarted = true;
                }
                if (!muxerStarted)
                    break;
            } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result fr om encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
            } else { // encoderStatus >= 0
                try {
                    ByteBuffer encodedData = audioOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                    if (encodedData == null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                        break;
                    }
                    // It's usually necessary to adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo.
                    encodedData.position(audioBufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(audioBufferInfo.offset + audioBufferInfo.size);
                    if (muxerStarted)
                        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(audioTrackIndex, encodedData, audioBufferInfo);
                    isRunning = isRunning && (audioBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) == 0;
                    audioEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                    if ((audioBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebRtcAudioRecordSamplesReady(JavaAudioDeviceModule.AudioSamples audioSamples) {
        if (!isRunning)
            return;
        audioThreadHandler.post(() -> {
            if (audioEncoder == null) try {
                audioEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
                MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
                format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, audioSamples.getChannelCount());
                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, audioSamples.getSampleRate());
                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);
                format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
                audioEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                audioEncoder.start();
                audioInputBuffers = audioEncoder.getInputBuffers();
                audioOutputBuffers = audioEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, exception);
            }
            int bufferIndex = audioEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
            if (bufferIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = audioInputBuffers[bufferIndex];
                buffer.clear();
                byte[] data = audioSamples.getData();
                buffer.put(data);
                audioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(bufferIndex, 0, data.length, presTime, 0);
                presTime += data.length * 125 / 12; // 1000000 microseconds / 48000hz / 2 bytes
            }
            drainAudio();
        });
    }

}
```

then add this implementation for this recording MediaRecorderImpl.java

```
package com.vedja.hassan.kavandeh_master.utils;


import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;


import com.vedja.hassan.kavandeh_master.utils.utils.EglUtils;

import org.webrtc.VideoFileRenderer;
import org.webrtc.VideoTrack;
import org.webrtc.audio.AudioDeviceModule;
import org.webrtc.audio.JavaAudioDeviceModule;

import java.io.File;

public class MediaRecorderImpl {

    private final Integer id;
    private final VideoTrack videoTrack;
    private final AudioSamplesInterceptor audioInterceptor;
    private VideoFileRenderer videoFileRenderer;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private File recordFile;

    public MediaRecorderImpl(Integer id, @Nullable VideoTrack videoTrack, @Nullable AudioSamplesInterceptor audioInterceptor) {
        this.id = id;
        this.videoTrack = videoTrack;
        this.audioInterceptor = audioInterceptor;
    }

    public void startRecording(File file) throws Exception {
        recordFile = file;
        if (isRunning)
            return;
        isRunning = true;
        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        if (videoTrack != null) {
            videoFileRenderer = new VideoFileRenderer(
                file.getAbsolutePath(),
                EglUtils.getRootEglBaseContext(),
                audioInterceptor != null
            );
            videoTrack.addSink(videoFileRenderer);
            if (audioInterceptor != null)
                audioInterceptor.attachCallback(id, videoFileRenderer);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Video track is null");
            if (audioInterceptor != null) {
                //TODO(rostopira): audio only recording
                throw new Exception("Audio-only recording not implemented yet");
            }
        }
    }

    public File getRecordFile() { return recordFile; }

    public void stopRecording() {
        isRunning = false;
        if (audioInterceptor != null)
            audioInterceptor.detachCallback(id);
        if (videoTrack != null && videoFileRenderer != null) {
            videoTrack.removeSink(videoFileRenderer);
            videoFileRenderer.release();
            videoFileRenderer = null;
        }
    }

        private static final String TAG = "MediaRecorderImpl";

}
```

and use above code with this code

```
 final AudioSamplesInterceptor inputSamplesInterceptor = new AudioSamplesInterceptor();
    private OutputAudioSamplesInterceptor outputSamplesInterceptor = null;
    private final SparseArray<MediaRecorderImpl> mediaRecorders = new SparseArray<>();

       void startRecordingToFile(String path, Integer id, @Nullable VideoTrack videoTrack, @Nullable AudioChannel audioChannel) throws Exception {

            AudioSamplesInterceptor interceptor = null;
            if (audioChannel == AudioChannel.INPUT)
                interceptor = inputSamplesInterceptor;
            else if (audioChannel == AudioChannel.OUTPUT) {
                if (outputSamplesInterceptor == null)
                    outputSamplesInterceptor = new OutputAudioSamplesInterceptor(audioDeviceModule);
                interceptor = outputSamplesInterceptor;
            }
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorderImpl(id, videoTrack, interceptor);
            mediaRecorder.startRecording(new File(path));
            mediaRecorders.append(id, mediaRecorder);
        }

        void stopRecording(Integer id) {
            MediaRecorderImpl mediaRecorder = mediaRecorders.get(id);
            if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                mediaRecorder.stopRecording();
                mediaRecorders.remove(id);
                File file = mediaRecorder.getRecordFile();
                if (file != null) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, file.getName());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                }
            }
        }
```

finaly use this

```
 try {

        VedjaSharedPreference sharedPreference = new VedjaSharedPreference(getContext());

        final File dir = new File(sharedPreference.getStringParam(StaticParameter.SAVING_URL) + "/audio/");
        dir.mkdirs(); //create folders where write files
        final File file = new File(dir, "Vedja-".concat(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).concat(".mp3"));


        VideoTrack videoTrack = null;
        MediaStreamTrack track = slaveManagerActivity.remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0);
        if (track instanceof VideoTrack)
            videoTrack = (VideoTrack) track;

        AudioChannel audioChannel = AudioChannel.OUTPUT;

        slaveManagerActivity.startRecordingToFile(file.getPath(), 1, videoTrack, audioChannel);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Failed to open video file for output: ", e);
    }
```

Maybe after copying this code, some class is not found in your project. you can search this class on the internet.

Comment: @Suraj Rao
I'm having trouble initializing OutputAudioSamplesInterceptor. How can I create and pass the audioDeviceModule object?

Comment: audioDeviceModule = JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder(this)
                .setUseHardwareAcousticEchoCanceler(true)
                .setUseHardwareNoiseSuppressor(true)
                .setSamplesReadyCallback(inputSamplesInterceptor)
                .createAudioDeviceModule();

Comment: I can record video but not audio. When I enable audio recording MediaMuxer does not start.

Comment: How can I get the value of  "track" in this line - MediaStreamTrack track = slaveManagerActivity.remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0); ?

From where remoteStream is getting?

Comment: @Oliver how you resolve the no audio recording problem?

Comment: @MahdiAzadbar thanks for the detailed solution!! In my understanding "drainAudio" is used to get the AudioOutput (remote stream audio) right? Any guess why my `onWebRtcAudioRecordSamplesReady` cannot be triggered? My app does not need a microphone input but I enable its permission in xml.

Comment: Could you please let me know,  how to add both the `AudioChannel audioChannel = AudioChannel.OUTPUT;` and `AudioChannel.INPUT;`
I want to merge both audio in singlecall recording.

Answer (score 1):

in this project have a class VideoFileRendere you can use this Rendere for save video in file
 https://github.com/Piasy/AppRTC-Android

Comment: 2nd link is dead.

Comment: check if this can help u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031340/android-webrtc-record-video-from-the-stream-coming-from-the-other-peer

Comment: please check this and if know the answer please add it and I will give u reputation and will consider ur answer the correct answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201774/trouble-saving-a-video-file-with-webrtc

Comment: @Armstring, Thanks. It was helpful. I am also working on the same thing. Is there any way I can directly contact you...

Comment: @TanayMondal yes please do, here is my email: alex.balotelli2030@gmail.com