# Webrtc Android video call recording

Tags: android, webrtc

Webrtc Android Able to record video using this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201774/trouble-saving-a-video-file-with-webrtc-in-android/58670566?r=SearchResults&s=3|16.7047#58670566](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201774/trouble-saving-a-video-file-with-webrtc-in-android/58670566?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C16.7047#58670566)
but audio is not getting save. I have created javaAudioDeviceModule but drain audio never get triggered

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please edit your post and add some part of your current code so we can provide you a solution

Comment: thanks @behrooz able to record video with audio.