# How to record video and upload to server every five seconds using Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make an Android app where the user will recording a video and, the video automatically uploads to a server frequently(every 5 seconds).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045787/is-there-any-possible-to-send-chuck-streams-to-server-and-save-into-azure-storag

Comment: Hi , if other problem I will update my answer . Thanks for marking it in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess that you are developing video streaming to the server.

Here are some articles you can look at first.

[RTMP Protocol: Enable Instant Video Streaming for Android Apps](https://medium.com/@onix_systems/rtmp-protocol-enable-instant-video-streaming-for-android-apps-44cd9de6f339)

[Which Video Streaming Protocol Should You Use?](https://www.dacast.com/blog/video-streaming-protocol/)

[Which protocol is best for a video live streaming from a server to an Android: RTSP, RTMP, HTTP or something else?](https://www.quora.com/Which-protocol-is-best-for-a-video-live-streaming-from-a-server-to-an-Android-RTSP-RTMP-HTTP-or-something-else)

And a discussion of similar issues can be referenced.

[Streaming video from Android camera to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)

Last are some open source projects:

https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea

https://github.com/rhedgpeth/Xamarin-Yasea

Comment: Can i use WebRTC for fetch the video streaming data and store to the server?

Comment: @varunsanapureddy Yeah, you can use WebRTC to do that.(https://webrtc.github.io/samples/) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49830268/how-do-record-video-stream-data-as-mp4-in-webrtc-android) If be helpful, please remember to mark it.Thanks!